# Multiple button with multiple actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, actionlistener

I am doing a small Java project and using MVC graphical user interfaces to write. 
In this project I have dozens of button with different function.

Since I am using MVC to write, I won't use anonymous class listener. I would separate the actionlistener class in the Controller class. As I have dozens of button ,that mean I need to create dozens of actionListioner class for it??

If there is any way to simplify the code?

Comment: why can't you create specific methods and invoke them in anonymous listeners?

Comment: creating anonymous classes fo method delegates is the java way to go, since Java 8, you can use lambda expressions to have it a nicer look, though.

Comment: Make use of the `Action` API

Answer (score 1):

MVC is a structure to make easier to trace projects. It should not be a problem I think. Research please there are lots of information about it. You should use `e.getSource()`. Try this:

```
JButton b1;
JButton b2;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == b1) {
    // Do something...
    }
    if (e.getSource() == b2) {
    // Do something else...
    }
}
```

Please look these:

[One action listener, two JButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443259/one-action-listener-two-jbuttons)

[How to add action listener that listens to multiple buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936261/how-to-add-action-listener-that-listens-to-multiple-buttons)

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/Useoneinnerclasstohandleeventsfromtwobuttons.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is always a difficult thing for people to get their heads around.  Instead of letting the controller worry about the actual buttons, it should be worried about what the view is allowed to do (ie the actions it can perform), which (presumably updates the model).

So, your view would actually handle the buttons events internally, but, instead of changing the state itself, it would notify the controller the a particular state has changed or action has been performed.

This communication would be managed via a series of interface contracts.  This means that are particular controller is expecting to control a particular type of of view, but neither care about the actual implementation, so long as the contract between the two is maintained

With this in mind, it then means that your view can do what ever it likes and generate the "events" in anyway it likes, so long as the contract is upheld and you're not exposing parts of your view to other parts of the program which has no reason to reference it